# How in swift to convert Int16 to two UInt8 Bytes

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation

I have some binary data that encodes a two byte value as a signed integer.

```
bytes[1] = 255  // 0xFF
bytes[2] = 251  // 0xF1
```

### Decoding

This is fairly easy - I can extract an `Int16` value from these bytes with:

```
Int16(bytes[1]) << 8 | Int16(bytes[2])
```

### Encoding

This is where I'm running into issues.  Most of my data spec called for `UInt` and that is easy but I'm having trouble extracting the two bytes that make up an `Int16`

```
let nv : Int16 = -15
UInt8(nv >> 8) // fail
UInt8(nv)      // fail
```

### Question

How would I extract the two bytes that make up an `Int16` value

Comment: Unsigned to signed works, but might overflow. Signed to unsigned may result in nonsense so it's blocking you. What do you want out of this? -15 cannot be represented in unsigned.

Comment: I am trying to get the bytes that would represent -15 to store them back in an array

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should work with unsigned integers:

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [255, 251]
let uInt16Value = UInt16(bytes[0]) << 8 | UInt16(bytes[1])
let uInt8Value0 = uInt16Value >> 8
let uInt8Value1 = UInt8(uInt16Value & 0x00ff)
```

If you want to convert UInt16 to bit equivalent Int16 then you can do it with specific initializer:

```
let int16Value: Int16 = -15
let uInt16Value = UInt16(bitPattern: int16Value)
```

And vice versa:

```
let uInt16Value: UInt16 = 65000
let int16Value = Int16(bitPattern: uInt16Value)
```

In your case:

```
let nv: Int16 = -15
let uNv = UInt16(bitPattern: nv)

UInt8(uNv >> 8)
UInt8(uNv & 0x00ff)
```

Comment: My data spec requires I decode these two bytes as Signed Ints, the decoding is working

Comment: Updated the answer. You should first convert your `Int16` value to `UInt16` and then split it to two `UInt8` values.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`init(truncatingBitPattern: Int16)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UInt8_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/UInt8/s:FVSs5UInt8cFMS_FT20truncatingBitPatternVSs5Int16_S_) initializer:

```
let nv: Int16 = -15
UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: nv >> 8) // -> 255
UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: nv) // -> 241
```

Comment: UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: nv) on Swift 4

Answer (score 3):

I would just do this:

```
let a = UInt8(nv >> 8 & 0x00ff)  // 255
let b = UInt8(nv & 0x00ff)       // 241
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Int16 {
    var twoBytes : [UInt8] {
        let unsignedSelf = UInt16(bitPattern: self)
        return [UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: unsignedSelf >> 8),
                UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: unsignedSelf)]
    }
}

var test : Int16 = -15
test.twoBytes // [255, 241]
```

Comment: Please check [how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.